How do I get names of meetings from shared Mailbox calendar?
I have a code that is working that lists all my meeting's names for my own Outlook account.
I'd like to do that with the shared mailbox account but it's not working. It keeps reverting to my personal calendar. Can someone help please?
Sub DemoFindNext()

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences

    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim tdystart As Date
    Dim tdyend As Date
    Dim myAppointments As Outlook.Items
    Dim currentAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
 
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    
    ''''''''''
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim sharedmailbox As Outlook.Recipient

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("sharedaccount@email.com")
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)

    MsgBox inboxItems
    ''''''''''
    
    
    
    tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date")
    tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date")
 
    Set myAppointments = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
 
    myAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
 
    myAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
 
    Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """")
 
    While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing"
        Debug.Print currentAppointment.Subject
         MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 'this is where it msgbox the names of my meetings
        Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext
    Wend

End Sub

As others have pointed, when I do this, no appointment names come up
    'Set myAppointments = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
Set myAppointments = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderCalendar).Items


myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) is your personal mailbox calendar.  Compare that to how you've accessed the shared Inbox in your posted code.

Replace
Set myAppointments = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items

with
Set myAppointments = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderCalendar).Items


When I do that, it doesn't list appointments any more. Do you think it's a code thing, or some account setting thing?

As in myAppointments.Count = 0?

myAppointments.Count is 4395
What I meant is that the While loop is not printing out the names of the meetings when I set myAppointments to sharedmailbox, but it prints them when I use the personal account

So, the Count is right, so I guess my question is how do I access them? Are they an array, how do I display them?

So you are saying the problem is that currentAppointment.Subject always returns an empty string?

Yes. MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject shows nothing, msgbox doesnt even popup

Which means it does no even get there. which can happen if Find returns Nothing. You really need to step through your code..

I know why! the code worked in my personal mailbox because all the meetings are throughout the day. But in the shared mailbox calendar, all the events are full day events. Do you know how I can modify this line to make it be able to find them? Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """")

What are the values of tdystart  and tdyend?

Clean the code to see if there is an impact.
Option Explicit

Sub DemoFindNext()

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences
        
    Dim tdystart As Date
    Dim tdyend As Date
    
    Dim myAppointments As Items
    Dim currentAppointment As AppointmentItem
    
    Dim sharedmailbox As Recipient
    Set sharedmailbox = Session.CreateRecipient("sharedaccount@email.com")
        
    tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date")
    tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date")
    
    Set myAppointments = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderCalendar).Items
    
    myAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
    myAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
    Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """")
    
    While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing"
        Debug.Print currentAppointment.Subject
        'MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 'this is where it msgbox the names of my meetings
        Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext
    Wend

End Sub

